# Best Practice: Generic Component with different services

Tags: angular2-services, generic-programming, angular2-components

Let's say we have a TableComponent. The TableComponent's purpose is to show super heroes and to remove/add them. To do that, it uses the HeroService.

```
TableComponent {
  constructor() {
    heroService: HeroService
  }
  getList() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(...)
  }
  addCharacter(character: Character) {
    this.heroService.postHero(character).subscribe(...)
  }
  removeCharacter(character: Character) {
    this.heroService.deleteHero(character).subscribe(...)
  }
}
```

Now we want to use the same TableComponent for our super villains. The villainService already exists and is ready to use. Also the super heroes and the super villains share despite all their dissension the same class. The only thing that differs is their service. What is the cleanest way to implement it?

My first idea was to expand both services like:

```
tableOptions {
  getList: this.getHeroes,
  addObject: this.postHero,
  deleteObject: this.deleteHero
}
```

and to modify the component like:

```
TableComponent {
  Input() service; // HeroService or VillainService

  getList() {
    this.service.tableOptions.getList.subscribe(...)
  }
  addCharacter(character: Character) {
    this.service.tableOptions.addObject(character).subscribe(...)
  }
  removeCharacter(character: Character) {
    this.service.tableOptions.deleteObject(character).subscribe(...)
  }
}
```

but I hoped for some best practice tips that might be cleaner. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best practice here is to separate components with display layer and containers with services layer. So your table component should only emit informations that something happend on table like:

```
TableComponent {
  @Input() data;
  @Output() addCharacterClicked = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() removeCharacterClicked = new EventEmitter();

  addCharacter(character: Character) {
     this.addCharacterClicked.emit(character);
  }

  removeCharacter(character: Character) {
     this.removeCharacterClicked.emit(character);
  }
}
```

and for example if you want to display heros and villains in one table then you can use this component in container layer:

```
@Component({
   template: `<app-table-component 
                [data]="characters" 
                (removeCharacterClicked)="onRemoveCharacterClicked($event)">
              </app-table-component>`
}
export class CharactersTableContainer {
   characters: Character[] = [];

   constructor(private heroService: HeroService, 
               private villainService: VilliansService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heros => this.characters = this.characters.concat(heros));
     this.villainService.getVillians().subscribe(villains => this.characters = this.characters.concat(villains));
   }

   // similiar method to add character
   onRemoveCharacterClicked(character: Character) {
     if (character instacnceof Hero) {
       this.heroService.removeHero(character).subscribe(response => {
       // when backend reponds without error remove character from local list
         this.removeCharacter(character);
       });
     } else {
       this.villainService.removeVillian(character).subscribe(response => {
         this.removeCharacter(character);
       });
     }  
   }

   private removeCharacter(character: Character) {
     // implement method for removing item from this.characters list
   }
 }
```

Thanks for this you can easly change logic in container and table component doesn't need to know what happens with data. Table component should only emit events and doesn't care about what happens with them. Passing service to component is not good idea. Remember always separate services layer (containers) and components layer (only takes input and emits events on outputs)